# Play server as a thrift endpoint?

Tags: java, playframework, thrift

I'm new to play framework and have previously only used PHP to implement thrift clients/servers.

I want to implement a thrift service using play.

Where should I put the java files generated by thrift in the play framework directory structure so they get picked up by the class-loader? I've seen a previous answer recommending building jars for them, but this seems like too much - I'll be tweaking my interfaces while I develop and don't want the overhead of building jars - plus I'm a bit rusty at java and never really got round to learning how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample working code on **Play! Framework 1.2.3** using **Thrift 0.7.0**:

**Server**

```java
// Play! Framework Server Controller
public class Application extends Controller {
public static void index() {
    render();
}

public static void api() throws ServletException {
    if (!request.contentType.contains("application/x-thrift")) {
        response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("text/plain");
        response.print("Unsupported Call");
        return;
    }
    try {
        response.setContentTypeIfNotSet("application/x-thrift");
        ThriftServiceHandler handler = new ThriftServiceHandler();

        Processor processor = new MyThriftService.Processor(handler);

        TTransport transport = new TIOStreamTransport(request.body, response.out);

        TProtocol inProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        TProtocol outProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);

        processor.process(inProtocol, outProtocol);
    } catch (TException te) {
        throw new ServletException(te);
    }
  }
}
```

**Client**

```
// Java Thrift Client Using HTTP Transport
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidRequestException, AuthenticationException, TException, UnavailableException {
    THttpClient transport = new THttpClient("http://localhost:9000/application/api");

    TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
    MyThriftService.Client client = new MyThriftService.Client(protocol);

    client.RPCMethod("some string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Thrift has a Maven [artifact](http://thrift.apache.org/download/), you can just link it as a dependency using the Play Framework [dependencies](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/dependency) configuration. The dependency to add to play will look like:

```
org.apache.thrift -> libthrift-0.6.1
```

Comment: that's for the library itself, not for the generated classes is it?

Comment: I'm assuming (maybe wrongly!) than once you have the library, it will have it's own requirement for paths, based on the "root path" of the application. This emans you cna put a new folder at the same level as "app" and those and add what you need there.

Comment: no, i think i'll need to compile my classes to jars and then put them in the lib directory